# Is there any way to identify reserved word in a code file through a program at runtime?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

Is there any way to identify the reserved word in a code file through a c# program?
I think there is a place where c# keeps its tokens.
 where I can match my file words and identify them as a reserved word or not s reserved word.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filepath = @"C:\Users\yasir\Documents\Visual Studio 
      2017\Projects\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\ProductsController.cs";
        StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(filepath); 
           //path of the file



        var lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).Count(line => 
          !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line));
        string strFileContent = sreader.ReadToEnd(); //Read all the content
        sreader.Close();


        string[] words = strFileContent.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n' 
          }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
        //Split by words and remove new lines empty entries

        foreach( string ew in words)
        {

            //here i have to write check reserved word logic...
        }

        Console.Write(lineCount);


        Console.ReadKey();
        }

        }
        }
```

Comment: Easy. search for a list of keywords, however , im sure this is not what you are a looking for, therefor you need to add more detail

Comment: i have to check how many a c# file contains reserved word through c# program at run time

Comment: Here is a list of keywords in C# and contextual words https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ why not just search for them? however contextual words will be a lot hard. though i still dont understand why or what you are doing so this is probably not any help

Comment: i have to check it at run time

Comment: this is a compiler construction task to identify reserved word

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. (I'd use Roslyn for a start rather than CSharpCodeProvider.) For example, what would you do with contextual keywords? Sometimes they're used as keywords, sometimes as identifiers... Please provide a lot more detail in your question.

Comment: I just have to identify reserved words contextual words  and count how many these words occurring in a program file

Comment: let me edit question

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Samples-and-Walkthroughs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first i take all words in external file to a list

```
     string[] words = strFileContent.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n', 
     '.', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

then i make a list for tokens

```
   List<string> keywords = new List<string> 
    {"id","set","return","Id","EventHandler<EventArgs>",
    "eventhandler","event","collections","system",
    "abstract", "as", "base", "bool", "break", "byte", "case", "catch", 
    "char", "checked", "class", "const", "continue", "decimal", "default", 
    "delegate", "do", "double", "else", "enum", "event", "explicit", 
    "extern", "false", "finally", "fixed", "float", "for", "foreach", 
    "goto", "if", "implicit", "in", "int", "interface", "internal", "is", 
    "lock", "long", "namespace", "new", "null", "object", "operator", "out", 
    "override", "params", "private", "protected", "public", "readonly", 
    "ref", "return", "sbyte", "sealed", "short", "sizeof", "stackalloc", 
    "static", "string", "struct", "switch", "this", " throw", "true", "try", 
    "typeof", "uint", "ulong", "unchecked", "unsafe", "ushort", "using", 
    "using", "static", "virtual", "void", "volatile", "while" };
```

then comparing each word of file with every element in this list we will get the reserved word

```
  var ikeywords = words.Select(i => 
       i.ToString()).Intersect(keywords).ToList();
```

i have written this full program for

-identifying reserved word

-counting external file line

-identify and  Delete comments

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

   namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
    class Program
      {
           static void Main(string[] args)
        {


      string filepath = @"C:\Users\yasir\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Product.cs";
        //1.getting file count
        int linecount = CountLines(filepath);
        Console.WriteLine($"total number of lines in program file is:{linecount}");
        //2.identifying reserved words
        ReservedWords(filepath);

        //discarding comments
       Console.WriteLine( DeleteComments(filepath));





        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static void ReservedWords(string filepath)
    {

        StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(filepath);


        string strFileContent = sreader.ReadToEnd(); 
        string[] words = strFileContent.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n', '.', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);



        List<string> keywords = new List<string> { "id","set","return","Id","EventHandler<EventArgs>","eventhandler","event","collections","system","abstract", "as", "base", "bool", "break", "byte", "case", "catch", "char", "checked", "class", "const", "continue", "decimal", "default", "delegate", "do", "double", "else", "enum", "event", "explicit", "extern", "false", "finally", "fixed", "float", "for", "foreach", "goto", "if", "implicit", "in", "int", "interface", "internal", "is", "lock", "long", "namespace", "new", "null", "object", "operator", "out", "override", "params", "private", "protected", "public", "readonly", "ref", "return", "sbyte", "sealed", "short", "sizeof", "stackalloc", "static", "string", "struct", "switch", "this", " throw", "true", "try", "typeof", "uint", "ulong", "unchecked", "unsafe", "ushort", "using", "using", "static", "virtual", "void", "volatile", "while" };

        var ikeywords = words.Select(i => i.ToString()).Intersect(keywords).ToList();

        int result = 0;

        foreach (string ew in ikeywords)
        {


            result = result + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(ew + Environment.NewLine);



        }
        Console.WriteLine($"total number of keywords in program file is:{result}");



    }

    public static int CountLines(string filepath)
    {
        StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(filepath);
        string strFileContent = sreader.ReadToEnd(); //Read all the content
        string[] words = strFileContent.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n', '.', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        //Split by words and remove new lines empty entries
        sreader.Close();

        var lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).Count(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line));

        return lineCount;
    }

    public static string DeleteComments(string filename)
    {

        Regex comments1 = new Regex(@"//.*?\n",RegexOptions.Multiline);
        Regex comments2 = new Regex(@"\s*/\*.*? \*/\s*",RegexOptions.Singleline);

        string all_text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
        string afterRemoval = comments1.Replace(all_text, " ");
        afterRemoval = comments2.Replace(afterRemoval, " ");

        return afterRemoval;

    }

}
}
```